# Which Articles in the UDHR are related to women's rights?

Tags: human-rights

Which of the 30 articles are related to protecting women from assault and other violence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [The Universal Declaration of Human Rights](http://www.un.org/en/universal-declaration-human-rights/)

---

### Article 5.

> No one shall be subjected to torture or to cruel, inhuman or
>   degrading treatment or punishment.

### Article 12.

> No one shall be subjected to arbitrary interference with his privacy,
>   family, home or correspondence, nor to attacks upon his honour and
>   reputation. Everyone has the right to the protection of the law
>   against such interference or attacks.

But the UDHR treat all people equally, so it wouldn't be specifically for woman, it would be for everyone.

### Article 30.

> Nothing in this Declaration may be interpreted as implying for any
>   State, group or person any right to engage in any activity or to
>   perform any act aimed at the destruction of any of the rights and
>   freedoms set forth herein.

Answer (score 1):

The UDHR does not spell out any rights which apply to women specifically. It does instead emphasize in multiple places that any rights granted by it apply to men and women equally.

**Article 1** says:

> **All human beings** are born free and equal in dignity and rights.

**Article 2** says:

> Everyone is entitled to all the rights and freedoms set forth in this Declaration, without distinction of any kind, such as race, colour, **sex**, language, [...]

The word "women" only appears in **Article 16**, which is concerned with the right to marriage and which mandates that men and women have the same rights in a marriage and that none may be forced to marry against their will:

> (1) Men **and women** of full age, without any limitation due to race, nationality or religion, have the right to marry and to found a family. They are entitled to equal rights as to marriage, during marriage and at its dissolution.
>
> (2) Marriage shall be entered into only with the free and full consent of the intending spouses.

There is also **Article 25** which spells out an entitlement to special care and assistance for "motherhood". According to traditional gender theory, motherhood would only apply to women, but more progressive approaches to gender theory might allow for people who not identify as women to be considered mothers.

> (2) Motherhood and childhood are entitled to special care and assistance.

(all emphasis mine)

So according to the UDHR, women are protected from assault and other violence in exactly the same way as men are. The articles which offer this protection are the **Articles 3 and 5**:

> Article 3: Everyone has the right to life, liberty and security of person.
>
> Article 5: No one shall be subjected to torture or to cruel, inhuman or degrading treatment or punishment.